# Importing within project - modules not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a project with the current structure, but some of my imports are not working when I *think* they should be. Shoudn't these imports work since the folders are properly marked as modules?

```
foo
├── app
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── folder1
│   │   ├── aaa.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── folder2
│   │   ├── bbb.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── folder3
│   │   ├── ccc.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
├── README.md
└── .gitignore
```

**WORKS**

aaa.py

```
class X():
    pass
```

main.py

```
from folder1.aaa import X
```

PWD: foo folder

CMD: python app/main.py

---

**DOES NOT WORK**

aaa.py

```
class X():
    pass
```

main.py

```
from app.folder1.aaa import X
```

PWD: foo folder

CMD: python app/main.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo/app/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app.folder1.aaa import X
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

---

**DOES NOT WORK**

aaa.py

```
from app.folder2.bbb import Y
class X(Y):
    pass
```

bbb.py

```
class Y():
    pass
```

main.py

```
from folder1.aaa import X
```

PWD: foo folder

CMD: python app/main.py

```
  File "foo/app/folder1/aaa.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app.folder2.bbb import Y
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

Comment: You can make this work by adding the parent folder to the path, using something like  `sys.path.append( os.dirname(__file__)+'/..')`.

Comment: You may want to read [this](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html). Specifically, you may want to read about how sys.path is set and how it changes depending on how you run a script or repl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python import works by searching the paths in sys.path.
check whether app is added to sys.path by running the below code

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

if it is not present in this list, append sys.path by including app directory.

```
import sys
import os
current_loc = os.path.realpath(__file__)
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(current_loc))
sys.path.append(parent_dir)
```